# What to write in htaccess file for form method GET to url address?

Tags: .htaccess

Here is html form;

```
<form name="x" action="x.php" method="get">
```

when I press submit I get;

> /x.php?a1=a1&a2=a2&a3=a3&a4=a4&a5=a5&a6=a6

I want:

> /a1-a2-a3/

I don't want `a4,a5,a6`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the URL to show up like /a1-a2-a3/ in the browser's address bar when they click "submit", you'll probably need to employ some javascript to read the dom fields in the form and construct the clean "/a1-a2-a3/" URL and then point the browser there.

On the .htaccess side, it would take the "/a1-a2-a3/" and rewrite it back to "/x.php?a1=a1&a2=a2&a3=a3", I presume? Without more details it's impossible to write specific rules to accomplish this, but they'd look something along the lines of:

```
RewriteRule ^([\-]+)-([\-]+)-([\-]+)/ /x.php?$1=$1&$2=$2&$3=$3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.i use;

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /x.php?a1=$1&a2=$2&a3=$3&a4=a4&a5=a5&a6=a6 [L,QSA]

which works directly if i paste it on address bar.But when i press input submit then it goes www.domain.com/x.php?a1=a1&a2=a2&a3=a3&a4=a4&a5=a5&a6=a6

Comment: See the first part of my answer, you won't be able to change what's in the address bar unless you do something like using javascript to extract the form values and constructing the /a1-a2-a3/ style URL. The <FORM> tag will **always** give you a URL with the ?/& query string.

Comment: I don't know anything offhand, but something along the lines of this may help you http://www.bennadel.com/blog/695-Ask-Ben-Getting-Query-String-Values-In-JavaScript.htm